# Find an item inside of listception?

Tags: c#, list

I have multiple lists which are inside of lists ( I know it is confusing...)

An example:

[items of list1]
-a
-b
-c

[items of a or b or c]
-q
-w
-e

[items of q or w or e]
-g
-h
-j

...

But I don't know how many lists but I have to find an specific items through the listception.

How can I find them I tried something with "foreach" but I don't know how to do algorithm.

I hope you understand my question, waiting for your helps.

Regards.

EDIT: You can think like you have a folder which has many folders inside of folders and you have to find a specific file inside of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have such a complex tree-like structure, it would be much easier to use Dictionary instead of List (like folders with names), so you can define the content with the key.
Searching in a tree of Lists is very expensive (for resources and time)!